# How to write a maple program to calculate the product of polynomial factors missing some factors?

Tags: maple

How to write a maple program to find the following products

$\prod\limits_{j=1,j\neq 5}^{100} s-a_j$

$\prod\limits_{j=1,j\neq 6,11}^{100} s-a_j$

$\prod\limits_{j=1,j\neq 2,9,25,68}^{100} s-a_j$

etc.

Comment: Are you looking for specific techniques to multiply the factors out into a polynomial? Or is this simply an issue of not knowing how to write an algorithm to multiply linear factors together?

Comment: I want simple commands (program) for it

Comment: Then I think your on the wrong forum lol

Comment: I am a novice, I don't know the simple commands(if any) for the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mul(s-a[j], j in {$1..100} minus {2,9,25,68});
```